# Probability of every combination in a quiz of 40 questions

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

Let's suppose we have a test composed by 40 questions. Every question has 5 options. Let's suppose that I didn't study for it, so for every question I choose one of the answers at random. Assume that I have $\frac15$ probability of selecting the right answer, and $\frac45$ of picking a wrong answer.

My questions (which should be relatively simple, but I'm stuck on it) is: what's the formula for calculating every combination of events?

For example:

0 answers right 40 wrong
1 answer  right 39 wrong
2 answers right 38 wrong
[...]
40 answers right 0 wrong

I tried =the simplest thing that crossed my mind. For example, for the first row (0 right 40 wrong): $\frac15^0\times \frac45^{40}$, as with the scheme $\frac15^\text{[number of right answers]}\times \frac45^\text{[number of wrong answers]}$, but when I sum up all the probabilities I get with this, the sum returned it's not 1 which I thought it should be.

Could anyone help me in that? Thank you.

Comment: Obviously, when I say "2 answer right and 38 wrong"... every combinations of the 2 right answers is possible (example: I made right the first and second question, or the first and the third, or the first and the last, etc. etc.)

Comment: You're not accounting for the fact that there are a different number of combinations for getting $x$ number of questions right and $40-x$ number of questions wrong. You really want the sum $\sum{{40 \choose x} \times \frac{1}{5}^x \times \frac{4}{5}^{40-x}}$ which equals $1$

Comment: I believe the formula you are looking for is combinations "n choose r" which gives the number of ways you can choose r from a set of n items. ${{n}\choose{r}} = \frac{n!}{r! (n-r)!}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not accounting for the fact that there are a different number of combinations for getting $x$ number of questions right and $40-x$ number of questions wrong. You really want the sum $\sum{{40 \choose x}\frac{1}{5}^x}\frac{4}{5}^{40-x}$

Answer (score 0):

Consider one right answer, 39 wrong answers.

calculate the following probabilities:

i) What's the probability that the *first* answer is right and the next 39 are wrong?

ii) What's the probability that the *second* answer is right and the other 39 are wrong?

iii) What's the probability that the *third* answer is right and the other 39 are wrong?

$\vdots$

xl) What's the probability that the *last* answer is right and the other 39 are wrong?

Now add those up!